# Use property in formula

Tags: excel, properties, formula

I've added to my Excel file a new property `prop`.

picture of my property from the settings

[image]

I would now like to use the property in a formula, like `=VERKETTEN(""; prop; "")`.

But this doesn't work :(
Is there a way to use those properties in formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use the property in a formula, you'd have to use a macro or UDF, and reference the [workbook.customdocumentproperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.customdocumentproperties) object to get the value.

However, to suggest a slightly different approach, there is a way to [link a custom property to a cell](https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2013/06/epdm-using-link-to-content-to-define-custom-file-properties-in-excel/) in the workbook, meaning that the property will update when that cell is changed. The cell is a normal cell so can also be referenced in formulas.
Whether this is a suitable approach is of course dependent on how and when the custom property is set / changed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a name with a constant value?

[image]